# Calling stored procedure from asp.net doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ado.net, sql-update

I wrote a stored procedure to update `PAID` column in `tblUser`, and that stored proceudre works perfectly,

Code:

```
    @buyer_email varchar(50),
    @payment bit
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update tblUser set paid=@payment where email = @buyer_email
END
```

but when I call it from my asp.net app then it doesn't update the `Paid` column, even if I try simple update statement in my asp.net code but that also doesn't update the column.

```
String userEmail_send = (Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["emailAdmin"]));
String conString = "Data Source=COSANOSTRA; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Initial   Catalog=Waleed_orsfinal;Integrated Security=True";

try
{
         con.Open();

        if (userEmail_get.Replace("'", string.Empty) == userEmail_send.Replace("''", string.Empty))
        {
            //String query1 = "update tblUser Set paid=1 where email='" + userEmail_send + "' ";
            SqlCommand sqlcom1 = new SqlCommand("submitPaypalPayment", con);
            sqlcom1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcom1.Parameters.Add("@buyer_email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userEmail_send;
            sqlcom1.Parameters.Add("@payment", SqlDbType.Bit).Value= 1 ;
            sqlcom1.ExecuteScalar();

            hdr_msg_success.InnerText = "Congrats, You have paid successfully. Wait for an approval by an admin ";
            Response.Write("<br/>"+" "+ "Matched=" +userEmail_send.Replace("''","'"));
   }
   else
   {
            hdr_msg_success.InnerText = "Something went wrong in matching Emails , Please confirm your Email";               
   }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
        Response.Write(exc.Message);
}
finally
{
        con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why do you use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery()?

Comment: no, no error and yes i tried ExecuteScalar and executenonquery(), both but it has the same problem

Comment: Is the success message being returned? Or more specifically, is the code entering the first part of the 'if' block?

Comment: yes the message being returned, but thing is that it doesn't update the field to 1

Comment: it does gove me the message that i embedded in if block but doesn't update vale

Comment: additionally, i am using the same connection to select user id from same table, and assigning that to session but i didn't post that code, and i have turned MARS to true, just saying

Comment: when i pass hardcoded string then it Updates the field where string matches but when i pass a value which i get from query string then it doesn't work, even query string gets displayed via Response.Write, which assures the querystring isn't empty
why it works with hardcoded string but not querystring variable or session.

Answer (score 1):

The failure is likely due to your connectionstring security context.
Assuming you're running under IIS impersonation of the current web user is not the default behavior.

By specifying `Integrated Security=True` in your connectionstring you're telling SQL Server to accept the current Windows context as the user attempting to gain access to the database.  This will be the IIS Application Pool account, not your own account, when running under IIS.

Try creating a SQL Server user name and password and specifying them in the connectionstring instead of using integrated security with a web application.  You could alternatively set the Application Pool Windows Identity but that's something that's usually more cumbersome to maintain and migrate...  There's also the option of allowing web user impersonation but that's even more unwieldy.

By the way, here are some other things to consider...

1. Store your connectionstring in a config file, not hardcoded (I understand that this may just be test code, but if not...)
2. Consider interacting with your stored procedure from ADO.net with something more like this in your use case.

   ```
   using (SqlCommand sqlcom1 = new SqlCommand("dbo.submitPaypalPayment", con)) 
   {
      sqlcom1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      sqlcom1.Parameters.Add("@buyer_email", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = userEmail_send };
      sqlcom1.Parameters.Add("@payment", SqlDbType.Bit) { Value= 1 };

      sqlcom1.ExecuteNonQuery();

   }
   ```

Comment: hi, its just a test code, will integrate it in my original code if it worked, and i tried what u said but non of it helped :(

Comment: when i pass hardcoded string then it Updates the field where string matches but when i pass a value which i get from query string then it doesn't work, even query string gets displayed via Response.Write, which assures the querystring isn't empty
why it works with hardcoded string but not querystring variable or session.

Comment: varchar(50) for email is too small in many cases.  Could it be that the email value is being truncated for longer email addresses?  I usually use at least varchar(150) for fields to contain email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I read here, I seems like the values are not set correctly to the variables from the Request object.

Have you tried setting the break point and check what value is set to your userEmail_send variable from this statement 
[`String userEmail_send = (Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["emailAdmin"]));`]?

May be its not setting the right value for that variable.

Set the break point at this line `sqlcom1.ExecuteScalar();` and check the parameter values.

You can do that by the ordinal position or by the name of the parameter as shown below:
By ordinal position `sqlcom1.Parameters[0].Value` or by name `sqlcom1.Parameters["@buyer_email"].Value`

do the same thing for your @payment parameter as well.  Remember its ordinal position would be 1.

Hope, this helps... and good luck...